# Create PDF trough the command line cmd using pdfBOX [how to pass -ttf argument]

Tags: windows, command-line, pdfbox

I am trying to create a pdf file using pdfBOX by issuing the following command in cmd:

```
java -jar pdfbox-app-1.8.8.jar TextToPDF -ttf C:\ttf_fonts\georgia.ttf -fontSize 13 test.pdf test.txt
```

and I'm getting the error below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream.<init>(PDStream.java:120)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(PDTrueTypeFont.java:189)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(PDTrueTypeFont.java:175)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF(PDTrueTypeFont.java:162)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.TextToPDF.main(TextToPDF.java:193)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.PDFBox.main(PDFBox.java:100)
```

It seems that i cannot pass the `-ttf` argument. How can i tackle the above issue?

Comment: Known bug (PDFBOX-2559), has been fixed and will be in next release (1.8.9). Until then, use a snapshot version. https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/1.8.9-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: That was the culprit. But i cannot write Greek characters in the PDF file. Is it an encoding issue? Is there a way to control PDF encoding [a parameter maybe]?

Comment: Don't know... maybe that is available in the (unreleased) 2.0 version, try it https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: If it doesn't work with 2.0, open an issue in PDFBox JIRA, and attach the font and the text.